# Evaluation with bitwise operation

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

When checking whether n is a 2's exponential number, I wrote the following line:

```
if(n&(n-1)!=0)
```

to my surprise, when n is 6, this is evaluated to false. Then if I change it to

```
if((n&(n-1))!=0)
```

I get the correct result.

EDIT:

I get it that `!=` is evaluated first, but I still don't see how the result is false in the case where n = 6.
5!=0 is true
then 6&true should still be true right?

Comment: `if (n & (n - 1) != 0)` is the same as `if (n & ((n - 1) != 0))`

Comment: Unless it's simple addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division, I always use parentheses to force (actually show) my desired evaluation precedence, regardless of "language".  And even in simple arithmetic, I still use parentheses, e.g. `(a * b) + (c * d)` even though they are unnecessary programmatically (but definitely help in readability).

Comment: @MarounMaroun could you have a look at my edit part, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In expression you originally used, `(n-1) != 0` is executed first, then `n &` is applied to its result.

---

At the first sight it might not look logical, but `==` and `!=` have higher precedence than `&` or `|`.

It's a common C/C++ behavior and it has been already addressed by its criticism:

[Operators in C and C++: Criticism of bitwise and equality operators precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Criticism_of_bitwise_and_equality_operators_precedence)

Conceptually, operators `|` and `&` are like `+` and `*`, so having them with low precedence is not very intuitive and leads to questions like the one you posted.

Hint: in contact with any programming language, it is good to develop a habit of checking operator precedence topic whenever in doubt. Actually, you will find quite soon that you actually memorized it in the meantime.

Comment: But if `!=` is done first, 5!=0 should be true, which is 1, then 6&1 should still evaluate to true right?  I didn't down vote you btw..

Comment: On bool, & is the non-lazy version of &&, which explains why they have essentially the same priority, although that gets confusing with other uses of &.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the order of precedence is very important in here. From your second attempt the result is correct as this is called operator precedence (or "order of operations"). Precedence of common operators is generally defined so that "higher-level" operations are performed first (i.e., advanced operations "bind more tightly")/ For simple expressions, operations are typically ordered from highest to lowest in the order:

1. Parenthesization
2. Factorial
3. Exponentiation
4. Multiplication and division
5. Addition and subtraction

A common pitfall is that inner **`(`** that cause to change the whole balance. Same concept, however bit-twise operations have the lowest priorities.